# How to enable Pivotal SSO for React js app

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, cloud-foundry

We basically deploy our apps to PCF. We have built a React js app which needs to be deployed to PCF and it should have Pivotal SSO authentication enabled for its users. Could you please let know the process to deploy react js app to PCF with Pivotal SSO enabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do it.

1. Server-side. Any request to your application, like to just load the page, requires authentication. The server can then perform the [authorization code grant flow](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-identity/grant-types.html#auth-code). This is the most commonly used flow for login.

   How you'd go about doing this will depend on what is serving up your files. You'll need to look at how the server handles security and if it has integrated support for OAuth2 or OpenID Connect.

   It's certainly possible in other languages/frameworks, but here are a few examples:

   - If you're using Apache HTTPD, you can use [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc).
   - If you have a Java app, [Spring Security's OAuth2 support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/#oauth2) will work nicely. Seel also the [examples in the docs](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-identity/1-12/integrating-sso.html).
   - For .NET and Dotnet Core apps, there's [Steeltoe Security](https://steeltoe.io/docs/2/security/sso-open-id).
2. Client-side. You can perform the login using just Javascript in the client's browser, but the login flow will be different. Ideally, you could use the authorization code grant flow with PKCE but as I write this the SSO tile doesn't support that flow. That means if you want to do client-side OAuth2, you'll [need to use the implicit flow](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/single-page-apps/#implicit).

   I have always used option #1 above, so I can't recommend a library to use but you can [find a few here](https://oauth.net/code/javascript/). You can use any library that supports the implicit flow though. Then just [register your app](https://docs.pivotal.io/p-identity/config-apps.html#internal) and pick `implicit` for the grant type.